# How to show the dual map of an isometric isomorphism is an isometric isomorphism?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and $T : X \to Y$ an isometric isomorphism. Then how to show the dual map $T^* : Y^* \to X^*$ is an isometric isomorphism?

The map $T^*$ acts as $T^*(f) = f \circ T$ for all $f \in Y^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tsemo is correct, in that the fact that $T$ maps the unit sphere of $X$ bijectively onto the unit sphere of $Y$ implies that $T$ is an isometry.  Furtermore, note that 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Ran}(T^*)_\perp&=\{x\in X:\forall f\in Y^*,\langle T^*f,x\rangle=0\}\\
&=\{x\in X:\forall f\in Y^*, \langle f,Tx\rangle=0\}\\
&=\ker(T)\\
&=\{0\}
\end{align*}
Thus $\operatorname{Ran}(T^*)$ is weak$^*$-dense in $X^*$. But as $T^*$ is an isometry, it's range is norm-closed, hence weak$^*$-closed, and thus equals $X^*$.  Therefore $T^*$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there a easier way to show $T^*$ is surjective? Thank you!

Comment: Now that I think about it, there is a much more elementary way.  Since $T$ is bijective, it has an inverse $S$.  But then $S^*$ is an inverse to $T^*$, so $T^*$ is bijective (hence surjective).

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is an isomorphism and an isometry, $T^{-1}$ is also an isometry. We deduce that $T(\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\})=\{y\in Y:\|y\|=1\}$ This implies that $\|T^*(f)\|=sup_{\|x\|=1}||f(T(x))|=sup_{\|y\|=1}|f(y)|=\|f\|$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to show $T^*$ is surjective? Thank you!